# Varnish 4 Security Firewall

Tags: varnish

To secure my Varnish box I found this https://github.com/comotion/VSF
But it not compatible with Varnish 4. Is there any alternative plugin for varnish 4?

Answer (score 0):

They are porting the vcl files now for Varnish 4, if you know python or varnish syntax you can help speed things up. You can track the progress here on the [VSF github](https://github.com/comotion/VSF/issues/9).

Comment: Thank you Mike, hope it come soon!